# How to set Javascript "name" when link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, function, simplecart

When I click the button it preforms a function, I am now trying to make it so name: "", is entered when the button is pressed.

I added name="item1" inside the  tag but this does not yield the desired result.

```html
<img onclick="addbeat()" name="item1" src="button.png"/>

<script>
function addbeat() {
simpleCart.add({
     name: "",
     price: .99
 });
}
</script>
```

Comment: As mentioned in Sterling's answer and other comments, you should learn about `addEventListener` (and attachEvent if necessary) and move away from specifying `onclick="something"` inline event handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update for clarity**

You have 2 options here. If you're going with an inline event handler, then you can pass an event object to your click handler and access the image that was clicked using `event.target`, like so:

```
<img onclick="addbeat(event)" name="item1" src="button.png"/>

<script>
function addbeat(event) {
simpleCart.add({
     name: event.target.name,
     price: .99
 });
}
</script>
```

A preferable option (as pointed out in surrounding discussion) would be to programmatically attach your click handler- at which point you could use either `event.target` or `this`.

```
<img id="anImage" onclick="addbeat(event)" name="item1" src="button.png"/>

<script>
function addbeat() {
simpleCart.add({
     name: this.name,
     price: .99
 });
}

document.getElementById('anImage').onclick = addbeat;
</script>
```

Comment: This did exactly what I was trying to do! Thanks Brian!

Comment: the event object is passed inertially through `this` since it's a click event. `event.target` will work but it's a bit overhead.

Comment: `this` can be a Window reference inside of the click handler, given the example code posted above.

Answer (score 3):

You're using an event, so you can use the `this` keyword.

```
simpleCart.add({
     name: this.name,
     price: .99
});
```

Also, I highly suggest moving away inline events. It's messy and leads to unreadable code. Use an event handler!

```
var x = document.getElementById("imgTag"); //add id to HTML element
x.addEventListener("click", addbeat, false);
```

Comment: +1 but would also be helpful if you also showed OP the addbeat handler with event parameter... `function addbeat(e) { ... e.target.name ... etc. }`

Comment: You can't use `this` in the OP's given example - because it will refer to the `Window` object (not the image). You can only use `this` if an event listener is used the way you described.

Comment: @brianvaughn didn't know that, but if OP moves away from inline events, it will not reference the Window object.

Comment: Agreed, just wanted to point this out since this seems to be the settled on answer. (It's why I used event.target below..)

Comment: True, but he is right about inline events.  Easy enough to bind the objects correctly. +1

Comment: I agree with avoiding inline event handlers. :) Just wanted the chosen answer to be clear.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question, but:

```
<img onclick="addbeat(this.name)" name="item1" src="button.png"/>

<script>
    function addBeat(name)
    {
        simpleCart.add({
            name: name,
            price: .99
        });
    }
</script>
```

Does this help?

Comment: This will work, but it's ugly. Inline events introduce an unreadable aspect into javascript and should be avoided with external event handlers.

Comment: That's true, your answer is better than mine.

Comment: Better? No. They perform the exact same function. More readable? Yes. Not downvote worthy though!